# Trying to understand the precedence order in a sample code

Tags: python

I have two very basic sample codes below. The only difference is the order of the print statement and the if statement block. And they produce the same result. I am wondering if there is any difference between the two with regard to their logic:

Sample 1:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for num in nums:
    print(num)
    if num == 3:
        print('found 3!')
        continue
```

Sample 2:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for num in nums:
    if num == 3:
        print('found 3!')
        continue
    print(num)
```

Comment: "they produce the same result" -- no, they do not

Comment: They are not the same. Look closer.

Comment: I can confirm that when interpreted by Python 3.7.7., they indeed do not produce the same result, which is predictable from what the code looks like.

Comment: These two samples should produce slightly different results. Sample 1 should output `1 2 3 found 3! 4 5`, but Sample 2 should produce `1 2 found 3! 4 5`

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right, I didn't notice the difference at first. 3 is printed out in one sample and not in the other sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` skips the rest of the execution in that loop iteration, so in the first example, it's doing nothing. In the second example, it means that if 3 is found, the last `print` won't execute, as it's skipped over.

Also, the two versions don't produce the same result, since in the first one, when you reach 3, both `3` and `found 3!` will be printed.